# Positioning various types of node over a 3D Plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Now I've got my curves in 3D behaving the way I want, I would like to add text nodes and vector arrows and so on. Below is an MWE of my basic diagram and the first labelled arrow I've added. That was a lot of work for such a little addition. Is there any advice on how better to handle this, or is trial and error all I've got?

Good suggestion from Jake, my diagram is coming along. When applying this I had to use a hack - the white plot - to make space so that my arrows and labels weren't clipped. Any comments?

Also, what if I want to move all or some of the violet vector trio roughly 1 coord unit along the red curve either while maintaining their original directions or changing them? One reason to change them might be to keep two of them tangent and the other normal to the surface in which these curves reside. I'd have to do some of my own calculations of course, but what would be the best coordinates to express the result of those calculations and orient the vectors appropriately? I don't want much, do I?

**MWE**

[image: MWE Output]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\par\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scale=2,
    x={(-0.6cm,-0.3cm)}, y={(.6cm,0.0cm)}, z={(0cm,.6cm)},
    xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
    axis lines=middle, axis on top,
    xtick={1}, ytick={2},ztick={1},
    enlargelimits=true,
    clip=true
    ]
\addplot3[
    color=white,
    domain=0:4
    ]({x/2},{1.3*x},{x/2});
\addplot3[
    samples y=0,
    smooth, thick, color=blue,
    domain=0:sqrt(2)
    ] ({0},{4-2*x^2},{x});
\draw [-latex,color=violet,thick] (current plot begin) -- +(axis direction cs:0,0,1)
    node [anchor=west] {$ds$};
\draw [-latex,color=violet,thick] (current plot begin) -- +(axis direction cs:1,0,0)
    node [anchor=north west] {$dt$};
\draw [-latex,color=violet,thick] (current plot begin) -- +(axis direction cs:0,1,0)
    node [anchor=north] {$n$};
\addplot3[
    samples y=0,
    smooth, thick, color=green,
    domain=0:2
    ] ({x},{0},{sqrt(2-x^2/2)});
\addplot3[
    samples y=0,
    smooth, thick, color=red,
    domain=0:2
    ] ({x},{4-x^2},{0});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now that I have a better idea of what I'm doing I've focussed the question with some more detail.

Comment: I've edited my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Trial and error is definitely not all you've got, that should really be the last resort. The whole reason why one would generate graphics like this programmatically rather than using a GUI is that you can define the logical relationship between the elements of your graphic.

General advice: If you want to augment a PGFPlots plot with TikZ elements, move those TikZ commands *inside* the `axis` environment. That way, the axis coordinate system is available for drawing the elements, and you don't have to fudge the coordinates.

In the case of this concrete picture, it helps to think about what you're trying to depict: You want a line that starts at the start of the blue plot, and has a length of one z unit in the z direction. To draw that, you can add the line

```
\draw (current plot begin) -- +(axis direction cs:0,0,1);
```

directly after the `\addplot` command of the blue plot. The node `current plot begin` refers to the start point of the previous `\addplot` command. The `+` in a path command indicates a coordinate relative to the previous coordinate, and `axis direction cs:0,0,1` is a point that's one z unit in the direction of the z axis.

To get the arrow tip and the label, you'd use

```
\draw [-latex] (current plot begin) -- +(axis direction cs:0,0,1) node [anchor=west] {$n$};
```

[image]

Objects you draw using normal TikZ commands do not influence the plot range, which is why you used the invisible `\addplot` command. A better way to do this would be to explicitly set the upper limit using `ymax=5`, or to prevent cutting off the objects by setting `clip=false`.

To move the trihedron along the plot, define a new coordinate by adding `coordinate [pos=0.3] (trihedron origin)` at the end of the `\addplot` command, then use that coordinate for drawing the trihedron (instead of `current plot origin`).

[image]

---

Code for the first example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=14mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\par\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scale=2,
    x={(-0.6cm,-0.3cm)}, y={(.6cm,0.0cm)}, z={(0cm,.6cm)},
    xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
    axis lines=middle, axis on top,
    xtick={1}, ytick={2},ztick={1},
    enlargelimits=true
    ]

\addplot3[
    samples y=0,
    smooth, thick, color=blue,
    domain=0:sqrt(2)
    ] ({0},{4-2*x^2},{x});
\draw [-latex] (current plot begin) -- +(axis direction cs:0,0,1) node [anchor=west] {$n$};

\addplot3[
    samples y=0,
    smooth, thick, color=green,
    domain=0:2
    ] ({x},{0},{sqrt(2-x^2/2)});
\addplot3[
    samples y=0,
    smooth, thick, color=red,
    domain=0:2
    ] ({x},{4-x^2},{0});

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Code for the second example:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\par\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scale=2,
    x={(-0.6cm,-0.3cm)}, y={(.6cm,0.0cm)}, z={(0cm,.6cm)},
    xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
    axis lines=middle, axis on top,
    xtick={1}, ytick={2},ztick={1},
    enlargelimits,
    clip=false
    ]
\addplot3[
    samples y=0,
    smooth, thick, color=blue,
    domain=0:sqrt(2)
    ] ({0},{4-2*x^2},{x}) coordinate [pos=0.3] (trihedron origin) ;
\draw [-latex,color=violet,thick] (trihedron origin) -- +(axis direction cs:0,0,1)
    node [anchor=west] {$ds$};
\draw [-latex,color=violet,thick] (trihedron origin) -- +(axis direction cs:1,0,0)
    node [inner sep=1pt, anchor=south east] {$dt$};
\draw [-latex,color=violet,thick] (trihedron origin) -- +(axis direction cs:0,1,0)
    node [anchor=north] {$n$};
\addplot3[
    samples y=0,
    smooth, thick, color=green,
    domain=0:2
    ] ({x},{0},{sqrt(2-x^2/2)});
\addplot3[
    samples y=0,
    smooth, thick, color=red,
    domain=0:2
    ] ({x},{4-x^2},{0});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, I like it. I scoured the documentation and can't find this stuff. `-latex` means solid arrow head? What if I want to slide my trio of vectors away from the `y-axis` along the red plot somewhat? Would you mind checking out my update to the question as well? I had a clipping problem with the other two vectors. Cheers

Comment: Okay, I found it. I'm going to stop whinging about the searching of a 439 page pdf and a 726 page pdf. The more you pick up, the more intelligent your searches get. Initially there was just so much that I was overwhelmed, but with some good feedback from TSE I'm gradually getting my head around around this thing.